# Refer to specific product ID in WordPress / WooCommerce in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I have this script that adds a download button to every product page in WooCommerce but I need to exclude a product page from having the download button.

I tried changing the first line to

```
if ( is_product() || $id() != "1514" ){
```

but it is failing, I think I am on the right track but need to reference it correctly (It should only enter the if function if is a product AND its not product ID 1514)

```
if ( is_product()){ 
$link = get_the_title();
$link =  str_replace(' ', '-', $link);
echo '<div class="download">';
echo '<a href="';
echo bloginfo('url');
echo '/pdf/Spec-Sheet-';
echo $link . '.pdf';
echo ' " title="Download Spec Sheet" target="_blank">';
echo 'DOWNLOAD SPEC SHEET';
echo '</a>'; 
echo '</div>'; }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it should be && instead of || in your condition in the IF no?

i.e. if it's a product AND if that product is 1514...

Comment: ok I tried that, I just tried if ( is_product() && ($product_id == 1514)) { but that still doesnt do it

Comment: Sorry it should be `if ( is_product() && ($product_id != 1514))` no?

Comment: Phill, thanks for the reply but it still didn't work... but the answer below solved it with css, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to hide this would be to just use CSS.

if the theme is using the `body_class()` function then the page will have its own body class. Something like `.postid-1514` and you can hide it using `.postid-1514 .download { display: none; }` this will completely hide it.

Answer (score 12):

the answer is

```
if(is_product() && get_the_id() == 1253) {
    //do stuff
}
```

works in pre_get_posts - didn't test in the product template, but if it doesn't, make sure you are in the loop and it'll work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
global $product;
if ( $product->get_id() != 1514 ) {
  
// your logic here 
  
}
```